# Standard Objects and External ID Field

Tags: force.com, salesforce-id

Is there any restriction on the standard objects that accept external id definition ? I am trying to migrate data between two organizations (using custom code using the Bulk/Metadata API), and I am trying to create external id for WebLink object but it is giving me error that I cannot create custom field on entity : WebLink

Where can I find information on what standard object support external id field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not that you cannot add an external ID field to certain standard objects; the problem here is that you cannot add ANY custom fields to certain standard objects, including the WebLink object.

Check out this link for a list of standard objects that can have custom fields: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm#i1436378